# Why am I continously banned from posting answers on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, post-ban

I have a very frustrating history using Stack Overflow, as every time I have a solution to a problem I saw asked there, I cannot post an answer as my account is banned. I have no reputation, but how can I raise my reputation if I am banned? I feel stuck. I got no helping feedback regarding this.

Comment: There I gave you some rep! ;)

Comment: I don´t know about your past stackoverflow activity, but just a guess: Your posts are not rule-conform at all. Like this here. This is not the place to ask something site-related.

Comment: Given that you have no answers on your account, I can only assume all of them were deleted?

Comment: You left three answers in a row that were not answers at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119506/virtual-member-call-in-a-constructor/5005016#5005016 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060447/reseting-the-form-when-usering-the-jquery-validations-plugin/4203017#4203017 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659254/vs-2010-beta-2-where-is-the-visual-studio-command-prompt/10042489#10042489 . When those were removed, you were blocked from adding others. If you wish to genuinely start answering questions now, write the community team at SE and ask for those answers to be dissociated.

Comment: Because you haven't taken the time to learn how StackOverflow actually *works*, and chose to just bang away.

Comment: The reason you can't delete the question is because it has an upvoted answer, not because of the downvotes. Ironically, by bumping the question with your edit, you've probably opened it up to more downvotes than if you'd just left it alone (not that I have or will downvote this, just an observation from past experience).

Comment: Voted to delete, agree it doesn't have real value anymore.

Answer (score 29):

While none of your answers received a downvote, all three of them were moderator flagged, and deleted by a moderator.  This is what probably led to the answer-ban.

Your first answer reads

> I did that and didn't help vote -1

Well, that's not really an answer to the posted question, is it?

Your second answer reads:

> Greg, please tell me why would anyone have a class SEALED (which
>   cannot be INHERITED) when it has VIRTUAL members [that is to override
>   in DERIVED classes]?

You're trying to communicate with another user.  Not only will that not work (Greg will never see your attempt at communication), but again, it's not an answer to the question.

> I couldn't vote for you John, but your answer was nicest! I did as described and it worked for me. As a comment, I observed that there is a "$.validator" in jQuery, but this hasn't the resetForm() method. And the validate doesn't return a "validator". The prove is that the returned object doesn't have the method that "$.validator" has. I find this a little bit strange, but this is probably the price of working at higher level of jQuery (instead of js).

Another attempt to communicate with a user.

Then, you posted this question on the wrong site, and it was migrated here.

You need to spend some time with the Help Center and learn a bit more about how Stack Exchange works before attempting to post again.